# Messing with unpowered fixture causes breaker to trip

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, light-fixture

The issue I'm encountering is this: I'm replacing an old light fixture, or just removing it so I can paint. Power is off at the switch. I get the fixture disconnected from the wiring, and then any jiggling of the wires causes the breaker to trip. How can this happen? I've touched the wires and didn't get zapped, so...

And this has happened on different circuits throughout the house. I'm baffled. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where in the world are you ?  A breaker can trip if the neutral is shorted to earth.  Power does not has to be on in that circuit.

Answer (score 4):

This is why:

[image]

You probably didn't touch *all* the wires. I'd advise anyone working on house wiring to have a good basic understanding of the fundamentals before diving in.

Answer (score 2):

**ALWAYS turn off the breaker if you are doing anything more with a circuit than just replacing a light bulb.**

There are three common situations that can cause this:

- Backwards Wiring

Switches are *supposed* to interrupt the hot wire. But if they are wired instead of interrupt the neutral wire then when you turn off the switch there is still a hot wire at the light fixture. Which means that any short between that hot wire and ground should trip the breaker. If that's the case, you are extremely fortunate that you didn't zap yourself instead.

- "Extra" Wiring

Power for the light can go *panel -> switch -> light*, in which case there should be only one hot wire at the light fixture, hopefully switched. But it can also go *panel -> light -> switch*, using what is referred to as a *switch loop*. In this case there is an *always hot* wire in the light fixture box even when the switch is wired correctly. That wire *should* be securely connected to a wire going to the switch and possibly to another wire going to another location - that is, it should not be exposed by removing the existing light fixture. But some people get the idea that "every wire in the box should be disconnected" when replacing a fixture, and that can lead to a lot of problems, especially if the breaker is not turned off.

- AFCI and GFCI

While they work differently, there are a number of different scenarios where a light fixture that is protected by an AFCI or GFCI breaker could trip the AFCI or GFCI portion of the breaker even when the switch is turned off. If the circuit breaker has a TEST button then this is the likely situation.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to turn off the breaker to remove power from the circuit. Turning off the switch does not turn off power to the circuit.

Be happy you're still around to type the question, and go shut that breaker off until the job is done.

If you didn't take before pictures of the wiring, you'll likely have a fun time putting the fixture back and getting it to work, as well.